# What table is used in an update trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

In an insert trigger I use table `'INSERTED'` to get the inserted values.
Do I use same `INSERTED` table in update trigger as well, or here comes in an `'UPDATED'` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERTED` contains the new values and `DELETED` contains the old values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for the new values, you do. For the values being replaced, you use the same `DELETED` virtual table as in a delete trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to augment the other answers - INSERTED and DELETED are available to triggers, but also to the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

If you're just doing relatively simple tasks, such as selecting or storing the inserted/updated data, the OUTPUT clause can help you avoid using triggers altogether, which is advantageous as triggers tend to be rather transparent.